# Installing tmux on Ubuntu from source

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I've download [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) and am trying to install it on Ubuntu 10.04.

```
$ ./configure 
Configured for Linux
$ make
cc -DBUILD="\"1.3\"" -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_POSIX_SOURCE -iquote.   -c -o attributes.o attributes.c
In file included from attributes.c:23:
tmux.h:30:19: error: event.h: No such file or directory
In file included from attributes.c:23:
tmux.h:831: error: field ‘name_timer’ has incomplete type
tmux.h:1025: error: field ‘key_timer’ has incomplete type
tmux.h:1086: error: field ‘event’ has incomplete type
tmux.h:1102: error: field ‘repeat_timer’ has incomplete type
tmux.h:1122: error: field ‘identify_timer’ has incomplete type
tmux.h:1125: error: field ‘message_timer’ has incomplete type
make: *** [attributes.o] Error 1
```

Comment: There's no need to crosspost, especially to an inappropriate forum.

Comment: Why don't you install it from the repositories? `sudo apt-get install tmux`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install libevent-dev and ncurses-dev:

```
apt-get install libevent-dev ncurses-dev
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to get it working on andLinux as well.